# How to identify if a OneDrive DriveItem permission identity is a group or a user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We are getting the permissions of a `driveItem` using Microsoft Graph as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Each returned permission object usually contains a `grantedTo` field that has an `IdentitySet` as its value. But the issue with that is that each `Identity` is always a `user`:

```
"grantedTo": { 
    "user": { 
        "displayName": "data Owners", 
        "email": "data@example.onmicrosoft.com", 
        "id": "94c3e81b-f6fb-43c6-8df5-b98462ccf191" 
    } 
}
```

```
"grantedTo": { 
    "user": { 
        "displayName": "Data Members" 
    } 
}
```

This occurs even though those are Groups. So there's no way, using this data, to identify with certainty what is a Group and what is a User.

We want to avoid any additional request to do so as this can become quite inefficient.

Thus we are asking is there a way to identify if it is a group or user, without any additional API requests? For example some undocumented query parameters or relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible because the [`IdentitySet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/identityset?view=graph-rest-1.0) itself doesn't distinguish between Users and Groups:

```
{
  "application": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identity"},
  "device": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identity"},
  "user": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identity"}
}
```

Comment: The [IdentitySet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/identityset?view=odsp-graph-online) for the OneDrive & SharePoint REST API  state that there's also a Group Identity. Is `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0` this REST API? If so the documentation seems inaccurate because a Group Identity is never returned for permissions, when using this API.

Comment: That doc set doesn't distinguish between v1 and beta/preview releases. More than likely this is why it's not being returned.